# Basic Salt-cloud config file for openstack/nova mitaka

Tags: openstack, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I am running a newly created OpenStack Cluster using the latest version (Mitaka)
and I want to use salt-cloud to prevision and manage some vm's. Form what I can see salt-cloud does not handle keystone identity V3 api and therefore it can not authorities and access the OpenStack ack api's

`sudo salt-cloud --list-images=my-nova`

my current provider config looks like the following since it looks like the openstack driver is being deprecated I am using nova. the identity url is identical to the one listed in horizon and I have tested using curl that the master can talk to OpenStack

```
my-nova:
  identity_url: 'http://controller:35357/v3'
  compute_region: nova
  user: admin
  password: pass
  project-user: default
  project-domain: default
  tenant: default
  driver: nova
```

running the above command I get the following message

`Failed to get the output of 'nova.avail_images()': The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)`

running a tcp dump on keystone I get the following:

```
..@.,..VPOST /v3/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
Host: controller:35357
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: python-novaclient
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 101

{"auth": {"tenantName": "admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "pass"}}}
```

By the looks of it salt-stack / python-nova is using the old v2.0 auth api which is not available in Mitaka. Have not seen any documentation, I proably missing something the the salt-cloud providers config to tell nova to use the v3 API